# Rotate image by y axis

Tags: python, opencv, rotation

I have got function `rotate` and it is rotate input image on input angle perfectly by y axis, but i faced with one of problem. The corners of output image are cropped, i think problem in bounds of image, but i am not sure.
My function

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math


def rotate_y(img, y):
    # change size of image
    width = img.shape[1]
    height = img.shape[0]

    # 2d to 3d (projection)  , and -> rotation point - center point (origin point)
    proj2dto3d = np.array([[1, 0, -img.shape[1] / 2],
                           [0, 1, -img.shape[0] / 2],
                           [0, 0, 0],
                           [0, 0, 1]], np.float32)

    # 3d matrix in  y
    ry = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 1]], np.float32)


    trans = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 1, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 1, 100], 
                      [0, 0, 0, 1]], np.float32)

    proj3dto2d = np.array([[100, 0, img.shape[1] / 2, 0],
                           [0, 100, img.shape[0] / 2, 0],
                           [0, 0, 1, 0]], np.float32)

    ay = float(y * (math.pi / 180))

    ry[0, 0] = math.cos(ay)
    ry[0, 2] = -math.sin(ay)
    ry[2, 0] = math.sin(ay)
    ry[2, 2] = math.cos(ay)

    final = proj3dto2d.dot(trans.dot(ry.dot(proj2dto3d)))

    # rotation calculates the cos and sin, taking absolutes of those.
    abs_cos = abs(math.cos(ay))
    abs_sin = abs(math.sin(ay))

    # find the new width and height bounds
    bound_w = int(height * abs_sin + width * abs_cos)
    bound_h = int(height * abs_cos + width * abs_sin)

    dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img, final, (bound_w, bound_h), None, cv2.INTER_LINEAR
                              , cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, (0, 0, 0))
    return dst
```

I want to receive an uncropped picture.

Comment: See https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/ and https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2021/01/20/opencv-rotate-image/

Comment: @fmw42, yes i have already read these articles, but there are only about rotate at x axis, i need 3d rotation (y axis)